# How can i display the total usage count for a specific coupon in woocommerce cart page?

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, coupon

I want to to display on WooCommerce cart page (i.e. on `woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form`) the total usage count for a specific coupon only after the same coupon is added by user in cart page and it's valid.

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find the solution.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_cart_table', 'coupon_count');
function coupon_count() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( ! empty( $woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons ) ) {
         $my_coupon = $woocommerce->cart->get_coupons() ;
         foreach($my_coupon as $coupon){

            if ( $post = get_post( $coupon->id ) ) {

                        $counter = $coupon->get_usage_count();
                        echo "<span class='name-coupon'><b>Total usage for coupon </b><b>'</b><b>".$coupon->code."</b><b>'</b><b>: </b></span>";
                        echo "<span class='coupon-counter'>".($counter)."</span>";

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this coupon label hook woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_label to display coupon count along with coupon code